# SQL; Functions and where clause

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, where-clause

I'm trying to figure out which country has the population that is closest to the global average country population.

I have the following relation;

```
   Column   |         Type          | Modifiers 
------------+-----------------------+-----------
 name       | character varying(35) | not null
 code       | character varying(4)  | not null
 capital    | character varying(35) | 
 province   | character varying(35) | 
 area       | numeric               | 
 population | numeric               |
```

I tried doing this, where I simply select the name, the population for the country, getting the average country population and just compare it with a where clause. Finally I would just put a limit 1 to get the desired result. Oddly enough, I couldn't do this, what am I doing wrong? I'm using PostgreSQL.

```
select name, population, avg(population) as gac 
from country 
where population <= avg(population);
```

The error; ERROR:  aggregates not allowed in WHERE clause
LINE 1: ...pulation) as gac from country where population <= avg(popula...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use [window](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) function:

```
select
    name, population, population
from 
    country 
order by
    abs(population - avg(population) over())
limit 1
```

Or [cross-joined](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html) countries with global average:

```
select
    name, population, population
from 
    country 
    cross join (select avg(population) gac from country) gac
order by
    abs(population - gac.gac)
limit 1
```

Comment: The first one + the use of the "over()" function I didn't know about was clean as f**k! Great, I've learned a lot, thank you for your help! Programmers unite! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can order by the minimal difference between population of one country and the total average

```
select name, population, population, 
       (select avg(population) from country) as gac
from country 
order by abs(population - (select avg(population) from country))
```

The last line does the following:

- get the average population from the country table

  ```
  select avg(population) from country
  ```
- substract the average population from the population of the current country (current row)

  ```
  population - (select avg ...)
  ```
- get the absolute value of that calculation - reverse negative values to positive ones

  ```
  abs(...)
  ```
- order by that calculation. It starts from the population with the lowest difference to the average population

Comment: Thank you for the help! It seems to work. But what does the last line actually do? I can't get a grip on it.

Comment: Great! Thank you once again.